# Optimize cloning image without cloning unused space

Tags: dd, fdisk, disk-image

I have a pi with a 32g sd.

```
michael@pi3:/ $ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       29804860 1773224  26791008   7% /
devtmpfs          468152       0    468152   0% /dev
tmpfs             472760       0    472760   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs             472760    6280    466480   2% /run
tmpfs               5120       4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs             472760       0    472760   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk0p1     64456   22208     42248  35% /boot
michael@pi3:/ $
```

Plugged the sd into a reader, and copied it.

```
[Michael@devserver ~]$  sudo dd bs=4M if=/dev/sdf of=greenbean_pi2.img
7416+0 records in
7416+0 records out
31104958464 bytes (31 GB) copied, 1615.61 s, 19.3 MB/s
[Michael@devserver ~]$
```

Not only did it take a million years, it was too large to place on a 16g sd.

How should I have done this so:
1) I only copy used space?
2) It can be copied to other media which is larger than the used space?

Comment: Is there any reason not to use compression (e.g. gzip)?

Comment: @J.J.Hakala  No, but I didn't this this was relevant as we are dealing with partition sizes.